# Java two-item tuple consisting of enum and long as ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, enums

I'm looking to have an array list that consist of a two-item tuple, which consists of an `enum` value and a `long` value.

I'm curious if I need to create a `POJO` for this then create an array list of that class or if there is an easier way like `ArrayList<EnumClassName, long>`.

If the second is possible, is an example of how to declare and add items available?

Comment: You can only parametrize `ArrayList` with a single parameter. I'd guess a POJO would be the clearer option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Commons has [ImmutablePair](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/ImmutablePair.html), which is what you want.  You would use it as

```
ArrayList<ImmutablePair<EnumClass,Long>>
```

There's also a version which isn't immutable, but you probably want this one.

Answer (score 3):

The second option is not possible. ArrayList has only one template parameter.

What you can do is this:

```
class MyClass {
    EnumClassName name;
    long l;
    ...
    // getters and setters
}
```

Then declare your array list like this:

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to get a `Tuple` class you may use something like

```
ArrayList<Map.Entry<EnumClassName, Long>> list; // by the way, you cannot use primitive types, such as long as generic parameters, that's why Long instead of long
```

The usage would be:

```
int index = ...//some index
EnumClassName e = list.get(index).getKey();
long l = list.get(index).getValue(); // autounboxed value
```

But the Java-correct way to do it is create a new class for it:

```
public class MyTupleName { // also, you should use more convenient name for the case
    EnumClassName e;
    long l; // names are also the subject to change alongside with getters
    public MyTupleName (EnumClassName e, long l) {
        this.e = e;
        this.l = l;
    }
    public EnumClassName getE() {
        return e;
    }
    public long getL() {
        return l;
    }
}
```

The usage would be:

```
ArrayList <MyTupleName> list = ...


int index = ...
MyTupleName tuple = list.get(index);
EnumClassName e = tuple.getE();
long l = tuple.getL();
```